# Python 3.x: Create dataframe from two dictionaries with different shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Similar to what's already posted here [Create dataframe from two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043484/python-3-x-create-dataframe-from-two-dictionaries). All keys are present in both dictionaries with the only difference being the shape of values that are arrays.

What I have:

```
d1 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([[2.5, 100], [4.5, 105], [7.5, 120], [9.5,137]]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([[10.5, 146], [11.7, 151], 
      [12.3, 164], [15.0, 173]])}
d2 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([15.6, 20, 23, 27])}
```

What is to be achieved:

```
d3 = {(1, "Autumn"): pd.DataFrame([[2.5, 100, 10.2], [4.5, 105, 13.3], [7.5, 120, 15.7], [9.5, 137, 18.8]], 
      columns = ["x", "y", "z"]), (1, "Spring"): pd.DataFrame([[10.5, 146, 15.6], [11.7, 151, 20], [12.3, 164, 23], [15.0, 173, 27]],
                columns = ["x", "y", "z"])}
```

Can you please help me out? I tried using the approach posted as answer. However, I get `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,2) into shape (4)` error.

Comment: Are you trying to create a `dataframe` or a `dictionary`? Also, can you tell us **what** the output looks like instead of **how** to create it

Comment: please see "what is to be achieved". I'm looking for dictionary of dataframes.

Comment: Please change the title of your question - it says `create dataframe from dictionaries`. Also, I just copied your code and it works fine for me. What version of Pandas and Python are you using?